# Xcode Swift Programming Adding Border Bottom issue

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, border, xcode7

I am using this code for Border Bottom. and It's working but  When I add some Constraints.(top,left,right positioning) Border Bottom is not working. What is the problem. (UITextField)

```
 let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - size, width: frame.width, height: size)
    layer.addSublayer(border)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
```

it's makes me crazy please help

Comment: How do you `add some Constraints`?

Comment: from Interface but I solved my problem.

When I put my code in viewWillLayoutSubviews and it works again :)